# LINQ using Automapper for a third level property

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I have three entity framework objects that are nested - see image below. Also, I have generated similar objects as DTO to map them.

So my question is, as the **companyDocument** object has a list of **ListCompanyDocumentsType**, when I execute a query to pick all companies, it returns a list of Companies and its Documents plus a list of documents types with a list of all documents that each type has within the database (like a looping).

Is there any way to return the companyDocument with only one document type? Or I have designed it incorrectly? To solve this problem, I've used a mapped object and a for each that returns the type name within a non-mapped DTO property. So it is working, but I'm not sure if it is the correct way.

Also, I've tried to use the EF .include() to go up to the ListCompanyDocumentTypes, but it is still returning all documents that each type has.

```
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto>(); cfg.CreateMap<CompanyDocument,CompanyDocumentDto>();});
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var newDtoTest = mapper.Map<List<CompanyDto>>(companiesReturn);

        var db = new entities();
        foreach (var companyDto in newDtoTest)
        {
            foreach (var companyDtoCompanyDocument in companyDto.CompanyDocuments)
            {
                companyDtoCompanyDocument.dtoTypeName = (await db.ListCompanyDocumentsTypes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p=> p.id.Equals(companyDtoCompanyDocument.typeId))).typeName; 
            }
        }
```

[image: Entity Framework Objects]

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ForMember()`,using this method you will be able to set the appropriate value for the specific field:

```
 cfg.CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.dtoTypeName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CompanyDocuments.ListCompanyDocumentsTypes.FirstOrDefault().typeName));
```

And `companiesReturn` should be a  `IQueryable<Company>` type, so your sample method `GetAll` `Company` need include `CompanyDocuments` and `ListCompanyDocumentsTypes` and  should look like:

```
public IQueryable<AttributeElement> GetAll()
 {
        return CompanyRepository.GetQueryable()
            .Include(d => d.CompanyDocuments)
            .ThenInclude(d => d.ListCompanyDocumentsTypes);
 }
```

Automapper has easy mapping, you do not need to use additional loops, everything can be set up in configuration class.